# How do I manage session stickiness/affinity in Tomcat container in Redhat Openshift when Reverse Proxy templates are reloaded between requests?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, openshift

Not looking for a code but a high level answer would suffice.

I have a Spring MVC web application which is deployed on Tomcat container in Redhat Openshift cloud platform. It is deployed on 2 servers, request can be routed to any one of them based on round robin algo.

Web application provides a functionality through a form in which Reverse Proxy (RP) load balancing routing weights for applications can be modified. Once user clicks submit, form information is *post*ed to the API and **RP templates are reloaded**. From Spring MVC's perspective there are 2 controllers, one for showing the form and another is to process the form information submitted.

Due to RP template reload (of the same infrastructure on which my web application is) a response from an API is received in back-end JVM but browser does not receive it, as it is lost somewhere between layers (Node apache, application HAProxy) from JVM up till RP because of RP template reload.

How can I manage to get response back to browser ? Do I need to use any session management ? If yes, which kind? Can I use JSESSIONID or OBSSOCOOKIE which are available in my controller ?

Let me know, if more information/controller code is required.

Comment: I also have similar query. Did you get any pointers to achieve this? If yes, please share.